# Adding background image to WebGL 3D scene

Tags: javascript, webgl

I wrote a code that tried to draw only the background image in a WebGL 3D scene. Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTexCoord.s, vTexCoord.t));
}
</script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    vTexCoord = aTextureCoord;
}
</script>

<script>
var VBack = [
    -24.0,  0.0, 0.0,
     24.0,  0.0, 0.0,
     24.0, 48.0, 0.0,
    -24.0, 48.0, 0.0
    ];

var vTBack = [
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0
    ];

var VBuffer;
var vTBuffer;

function initMatrix() {
    orthoMatrix = makeOrtho(-24.0, 24.0, 0.0, 48.0, 20.0, -20.0);    // From glUtils.js
    mvMatrix = Matrix.I(4);
    ...
}   

function handleBkTex(tex) {
    GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    GL.pixelStorei(GL.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    GL.texImage2D(GL.TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.RGBA, GL.RGBA, GL.UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex.Img);
    GL.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.NEAREST);
    GL.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.NEAREST);
    GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

function initBkgnd() {
    backTex = GL.createTexture();
    backTex.Img = new Image();
    backTex.Img.onload = function() {
        handleBkTex(backTex);
    }
    backTex.Img.src = "Bkgnd.jpg";
}

function drawBkgnd() {
    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, VBuffer);
    GL.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, 3, GL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, vTBuffer);
    GL.vertexAttribPointer(texCoordAttribute, 2, GL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    GL.activeTexture(GL.TEXTURE0);
    GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, backTex);
    GL.uniform1i(GL.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler"), 0);

    GL.drawArrays(GL.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}


function start() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("glcanvas");
    initWebGL(canvas);

    if (GL) {
        initShaders();
        initBuffers();
        initMatrix();
        initBkgnd();
        drawBkgnd();
    }
}
```

The canvas size is `512 x 512`, the same as the image size. But I don't get the correct image on the canvas. How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some small errors in my code. Here are they:

- WebGL scene **must** always be redrawn. So the function `drawBkgnd()` must be called repeatedly, using `setInterval()` or `requestAnimationFrame()`.
- To use `drawArrays()` with `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` to draw a rectangle correctly, the order of the vertices must be:

  ```
  *2        *3


  *0        *1
  ```

  or any equivalent order, but not:

  ```
  *3        *2


  *0        *1
  ```

  So the order of the vertices in `VBack` must be changed to:

  ```
  var VBack = [
      -24.0,  0.0, 0.0,
       24.0,  0.0, 0.0,
      -24.0, 48.0, 0.0
       24.0, 48.0, 0.0,
  ];
  ```

  and the order of vertices in `vTBack` must also be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the answer to be how to setup a 3D matrix to draw a 2D image or do you want the answer to be how to do this efficiently?

Here's the efficient answer. There's no reason to use 3D to draw 2D. Change your vertices to

```
var VBack = [
  -1, -1,
   1, -1,
   1,  1,
  -1,  1,
];
```

Change your call to vertexAttribPointer to

```
GL.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, 2, GL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

Change your vertex shader to

```
attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = aVertexPosition;
    vTexCoord = aTextureCoord;
}
```

And it should work.

See [this set of articles for more about 2D in WebGL](http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-fundamentals/) for more.

Comment: Thanks. However, as I wrote in the title, I want to set up a background image (2D) in a 3D scene. I've found the answer anyway.

Comment: What does "In a 3D scene" mean? If you want to fill the background with an image it's irrelevant the scene is 3D. Heck, you could also do it by just setting the canvas's background image as in <canvas style="background: url(img.jpg);"> then clear the canvas to 0,0,0,0 although my suggested method is still more efficient.